# Bamboo SCP plug-in: how to find directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cygwin, windows-server-2008-r2, bamboo

I am trying to upload a file to a remote server using the SCP task. I have OpenSSH configured on the remote server in question, and I am using an Amazon EC2 instance running Windows Server 2008 R2 with Cygwin to run the Bamboo build server.

My question is regarding finding the directory I wish to use. I want to upload the entire contents of C:\doc using SCP. The documentation notes that I must use the [local path relative to the Bamboo working directory](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Using+the+SCP+task+in+Bamboo) rather than an absolute directory name.

I found by running `pwd` during the build plan that the working directory is `/cygdrive/c/build-dir/CDP-DOC-JOB1`. So to get to doc, I can run `cd ../../doc`. However, when I set my working directory under the SCP configuration as `../../doc/**` (using [this pattern matching guide](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Pattern+matching+reference)), I get the message `There were no files to upload.` in the log.

C:\doc contains subfolders as well as a textfile in the root directory.

Here is my SCP task configuration:
[image: SCP]

Here is a look from cygwin at my directory:
[image]

Comment: What is the reason for using an absolute path in a build job? Where do the files to upload come from? Are they created by the bamboo job?

Answer (score 0):

You may add a first "script" task running a Windows shell, that copies everything from `C:\doc` to some local directory, and then run the scp task to copy the content of this new directory onto your remote server

```
mkdir doc 
xcopy c:\doc .\doc /E /F
```

Then the pattern for copy should be `/doc/**`